# incompatible pointer types (in C )

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

My list.h

```
typedef struct _list_object{
    void* object;
    struct _list_object* next;
}list_object;
```

My list.c, where I want to create a LinkedList

```
list_object* new_list(){
    struct list_object* linked_list = (struct list_object*) malloc(sizeof(struct list_object*));
    return linked_list;
}
```

But when I do it like this I get this error:

> warning: incompatible pointer types returning 'struct list_object *' from a function with result type 'list_object *' (aka 'struct _list_object *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
> return linked_list;

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to use either `struct _list_object` or just `list_object` (without `struct`). `struct list_object*` declares a new type

Comment: Aside the type problems, you're also allocating the wrong size: You need to allocate for the size of the list object, not the size of a pointer to the list object.

Comment: @datenwolf he can do it later. Now he is simply allocating the container

Comment: From the error message I would assume there is a type `struct list_object` defined somewhere that we don't see. Otherwise there wouldn't be a warning about returning wrong type but already defining the variable would fail. If you have some `struct list_object` and some `struct _list_object` they are not the same. Even if the members might look similar. Why do you define 2 different structs?

Comment: @0___________: Thing is, he didn't even allocate for the container, but just a single pointer. Also double indirected lists are kind of inefficient. The usual approach for implementing linked lists in C is putting a list link struct at the front of the payload struct and cast elements pointers to the link type (which is perfectly allowed as per the rules of struct layouts and type aliasing). For a practical example look at how the Linux kernel list and \*BSD queue are implemented.

Comment: @datenwolf linked list container

Comment: @Gerhardh: Using `struct list_object` when there is no prior definition of it immediately creates a type named `struct list_object` of incomplete type. So `struct list_object *linked_list =…` can never fail due to a missing prior definition of the type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right. I missed that it is a pointer. Compiler would only show an error for a non-pointer variable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the correct type or struct name.

```
list_object *new_list(void)
{
    list_object *linked_list =  malloc(sizeof(*linked_list));
    return linked_list;
```

or

```
struct _list_object *new_list(void)
{
    struct _list_object *linked_list = malloc(sizeof(*linked_list));
    return linked_list;
}
```

Also do not cast the result of malloc. If you have to then it means that you compile the C code using C++ compiler.

Use objects instead of types in `sizeof`s

If you know the size of the object you may use flexible array members. . It saves one allocation/free and also reduces the number of indirections.

```
typedef struct _list_object{
    struct _list_object* next;
    unsigned char object[];
}list_object;


list_object *new_list(size_t objectSize)
{
    list_object *linked_list =  malloc(objectSize + sizeof(*linked_list));
    return linked_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
typedef struct _list_object{
    void* object;
    struct _list_object* next;
}list_object;
```

defines a type named `struct _list_object` or `list_object`. Your code `struct list_object` uses neither of these; `struct list_object` is not `struct _list_object`.